# What are the Advantages and Disadvantages of JQuery and Glow JavaScript Libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbc-glow

Can anyone give a comparison of JQuery and the BBC's Glow JavaScript libraries?

Answer (score 8):

BBC's Glow JavaScript Library was just released. No one outside the BBC has much experience with it yet.

There's an Ajaxian discussion [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ouh-shiny-bbcs-glow-is-finally-out).

There's a bit of a dustup between jQuery creator John Resig and the BBC [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=693971).

Glow looks pleasant enough. It'll be interesting to watch changes land. It's open source, [hosted at github](http://github.com/glow).

Answer (score 1):

jquery has the advantage of far greater developer support.

As with the Creative Archive licenses (mirroring Creative Commons but restricted to UK), this is arguably a case of 'not-invented-here-syndrome' by the BBC.

As was pointed out in the thread linked to by Nosredna, Glow's selling point (compatibility with older browsers) could have been integrated with jquery via the latter's plugin framework.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most notable differences is that Glow supports **Safari 1.3 and 2.x**, whereas jQuery only supports **Safari 3+**.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a mature and widely used and extremely well tested library.  I do not know of any compelling features which Glow offers that can offset those facts.  So I would go with JQuery.